# Concurrent, non-blocking, fixed-size list?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency

I'm looking to implement a data structure with the following characteristics:

### Operations

- **Push**: Add an element to the front of the list.
- **Read**: Read all elements in the list

### Behavior

- **Fixed-size**: The list should not grow beyond a specified threshold, and it should automatically truncate from the end (oldest item) if that threshold is exceeded. This does not need to be strictly enforced, but the list should *eventually* be truncated once it passes the threshold.
- **Concurrency-safe**: The structure should safely accommodate multiple parallel pushers and readers
- **Non-blocking**: This is the real problem. I'd like to use an implementation without locks. Many threads should be able to push/read simultaneously if possible. A less-desirable, but acceptable option would be an implementation that has locks, but minimizes contention between multiple pushers/readers. I'm familiar with reader-writer locks, but those assume infrequent writes, which is not my use-case.

### Optional but nice-to-have

- **Write-read consistency**: If a single thread pushes to the structure, a read immediately following should contain the written item. This would be nice, but I'm wondering whether excluding this requirement could make the above requirements easier to implement.

I'm mostly a novice in concurrent data structures. Does an example of such a data structure exist? Ring buffers are interesting, but I don't think they can be non-blocking. Linked-lists are promising, but the concurrency-safe, non-blocking requirements complicate the implementation considerably.

I have found some good papers on implementing non-blocking linked lists using atomic CAS (compare-and-swap) operations, but the fixed-size requirement throws a bit of a wrench into those. Maybe that idea can be adapted to a fixed-size list?

For what it's worth, I'm interested in using this in Ruby. I understand that MRI has the global-interpreter-lock, which makes this a bit useless for MRI, but other Ruby runtimes could take advantage of this, and I'm thinking of it as a learning exercise to grow my concurrent programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with an interesting solution that meets the requirements.

### Theory

We use a linked-list as the foundation, but add thread-safety and truncation on top.

#### Pushes

During pushes, we accomplish thread-safety by using a compare-and-set operation. The push will succeed only if another thread has not already pushed to the last-known list head. If the push fails, we simply retry until it succeeds.

#### Truncation

When the first node is pushed, we designate it as the "prune node". As items get pushed to the list, that node is pushed further down, but we maintain a reference to it. When the list reaches capacity, we set break the link on the "prune node" to allow the following nodes to be garbage collected. Then we set the newest node as the "prune node". This way, the list size never exceeds "capacity * 2".

#### Reads

Because it's a linked-list without arbitrary insertions, we get mostly consistent reads because the list nodes will never be rearranged. We dereference the head when we start reading the list. We never read more elements than the configured capacity. If the list is truncated during a read, it's possible that we might not read enough nodes (this could be mitigated by saving the prune node when starting enumeration so that pruned nodes could still be read while the enumerator is active).

### Thoughts

I'm pretty happy about the truncation mechanism, but it seems likely that a Mutex-based solution would perform just-as-well or even better than the CAS solution. It likely depends on how heavily contested the push operation is, and would need to be benchmarked.

```rb
require 'concurrent-ruby'

class SizedList
  attr_reader :capacity

  class Node
    attr_reader :value
    attr_reader :nxt

    def initialize(value, nxt = nil)
      @value = value
      @nxt = Concurrent::AtomicReference.new(nxt)
      @count = Concurrent::AtomicFixnum.new(0)
    end

    def increment
      @count.increment
    end
  end

  def initialize(capacity)
    @capacity = capacity
    @head = Node.new(nil)
    @prune_node = Concurrent::AtomicReference.new
  end

  def push(element)
    succeeded = false
    node = nil

    # Maybe should just use a mutex for this write instead of CAS
    # It needs to be benchmarked
    until succeeded
      first = @head.nxt.get
      node = Node.new(element, first)
      succeeded = @head.nxt.compare_and_set(first, node)
    end

    # Every N nodes where N=@capacity is designated as the "prune node"
    # Once we push N times, we drop all the nodes after the prune node by setting
    # it's nxt value to nil.
    # Then we set the first node as the new prune node
    @prune_node.compare_and_set(nil, node) if @prune_node.get.nil?
    prune_node = @prune_node.get
    count = prune_node.increment
    if count >= @capacity
      if @prune_node.compare_and_set(prune_node, node)
        prune_node.nxt.set(nil)
      end
    end

    nil
  end

  def each(&block)
    enum = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      current = @head
      # Here we just iterate through the list, but limit the results to @capacity
      @capacity.times do
        current = current.nxt.get
        break if current == nil
        yielder.yield(current.value)
      end
    end

    block ? enum.each(&block) : enum
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Analysis

This question might be a better fit on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), rather than here on Stack Overflow, as it seems to be more of a design question. That said, I suggest using thread-safe arrays, or delegating resource contention to an MVCC database if you can't redesign your application to avoid a singular shared object altogether.

### Recommendations

You can implement a thread-safe list or simulate a circular buffer using [Concurrent::Array](https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/Array.html) with the #unshift and #pop methods. You can also choose to *externalize* locking to something like a database, where Ruby's GIL is largely irrelevant to the underlying queue or locking mechanisms. However, to the best of my knowledge, there's no way to create a truly lockless concurrent access object in Ruby, although implementing your own [multiversion concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) might come close.

The low-hanging fruit is probably to externalize your reads and writes to an [MVCC-capable database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html) such as PostgreSQL. If you can't or won't do that, you may need to accept the trade-offs inherent in the [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and performance characteristics of your application and data structures. In particular, the use of a single shared data structure is a design decision you should perhaps re-evaluate if you can.

Before you start down that path, just make sure that you have a real performance problem to solve. While there are certainly cases where locks add noticeable overhead, many real-world applications are sufficiently performant even with Ruby's GIL in the mix. Your mileage may certainly vary.

Comment: Thanks. Those are some good insights. Your thoughtful answer is very appreciated! I hadn't considered MVCC, although that's a bit too heavy weight for what I'm interested in. Agreed that Ruby isn't really the right tool for this, and that benchmarks are probably the first place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a class such as the following. I don't consider this to be complete. Moreover, I have not considered non-blocking issues, which is a broad topic that is not specific to this class.

```
class TruncatedList
  attr_reader :max_size
  alias to_s inspect
  
  def initialize(max_size=Float::INFINITY)
    @max_size = max_size
    @list = []
  end
```

```
  def pop(n=1)
    return nil if @list.empty?
    case n
    when 0
      nil
    when 1
      @list.pop
    else
      @list.pop([n, @list.size].min)
    end
  end

  def >>(obj)
    @list.pop if @list.size == @max_size
    @list.unshift(obj)
  end
   
  def unshift(*arr)
    arr.each do |obj|
      @list.pop if @list.size == @max_size
      @list >> obj
    end
  end
```

```
  def <<(obj)
    if @list.size < @max_size
      @list << obj
    else
      @list
    end
  end     

  def push(*arr)
    arr.each do |obj|
      break(@list) if @list.size == @max_size
      @list << obj
    end
  end

  def shift(n=1)
    return @list if @list.empty?
    case n
    when 0
      nil
    when 1
      @list.shift
    else
      @list.shift([n, @list.size].min)
    end
  end
```

```
  def pop(n=1)
    return nil if @list.empty?
    case n
    when 0
      nil
    when 1
      @list.pop
    else
      @list.pop([n, @list.size].min)
    end
  end

  def inspect
    @list.to_str
  end

  def to_a
    @list
  end

  def size
    @list.size 
  end
end
```

Here is an example of how this set might be used.

```
t = TruncatedList.new(6)
  #=> #<TruncatedList:0x00007fe2db0512a0 @max_size=6, @list=[]>

t.inspect
  #=> "[]"      

t.to_a
  #=> []

t >> 1
  #=> 1

t.inspect
  #=> "[1]"

t.unshift(2,3)
  #=> [2, 3]

t.inspect
  #=> "[3, 2, 1]"   

t.unshift(4,5,6,7,8) 
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

t.inspect
  #=> "[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]"

t.to_a
  #=> [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Right. That's a good implementation of the required operations, and it will work just fine on MRI with the GIL, but in a multi-threaded scenario with true parallelism, it's going to run into issues. Adding synchronization or using Concurrent::Array can fix that, but I'm looking for a solution that will minimize contention.